# pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: function public.st_accum(public.geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-restore

I 'm trying restore backup from pg11 postgis 2.5.2 to pg12 postgis 3.0.0, but restore failing.

If I drop postgis 2.5.2 on source server and install 3.0.0 will It cause the problem ?

details:

source db (where backup taken):

```
 PostgreSQL 11.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit
 POSTGIS="2.5.2 r17328" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL
1.11.4, released 2016/01/25" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" RASTER
```

target db (where restore):

```
 PostgreSQL 12.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
 POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " SFCGAL="1.3.1" PROJ="6.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0
.11" LIBPROTOBUF="1.0.2" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY
```

dump file:

```
  Dump Version: 1.14-0
  Format: CUSTOM
  Integer: 4 bytes
  Offset: 8 bytes
  Dumped from database version: 11.1
  Dumped by pg_dump version: 12.1
```

example errors:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.st_accum(public.geometry) does not exist
Command was: GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.st_accum(public.geometry) TO test_app;
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  type "public.raster" does not exist
Command was: GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.st_countagg(public.raster, boolean) TO test_app;
```